# Inconsistency with Clojure's sequences?

Tags: clojure, seq

Clojure:

```
1:13 user=> (first (conj '(1 2 3) 4))
4
1:14 user=> (first (conj [1 2 3] 4))
1
; . . .
1:17 user=> (first (conj (seq [1 2 3]) 4))
4
```

I understand what is going on, but should this work differently?

Comment: I have been learning Clojure since May of this year. I found delving into exercises like this to be very helpful, especially given I never learned a Lisp-like language before Clojure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Documentation for `conj` (from [clojure.org](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/conj)):

> conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs
>   'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item).  The 'addition' may
>   happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.

It's more efficient to "add" elements to the end of a vector, while it's more efficient to do so at the beginning of lists. `conj` uses whatever is the most efficient for the data structure you give it.

In the examples you give, `'(1 2 3)` and `(seq [1 2 3])` both implement `ISeq` (see [documentation for `seq?`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/seq?)), while `[1 2 3]` doesn't.

Clojure's `conj` ultimately calls the `cons` method (not to be confused with the `cons` function - this method is internal clojure code) on the underlying data structure; for vectors (`PersistentVector`), `cons` adds elements to the end, while for lists they're added to the front (the `cons` method for `PersistentList`s returns a new list with the new element as its head, and the existing list as its tail).

Comment: The last paragraph I think is incorrect (at least in Clojure 1.2.1): `(cons 4 [1 2 3])`, for example, does not append the element but prepends it, resulting in `(4 1 2 3)`. The rest of the answer, though, is absolutely correct.

Comment: You are right, Zach, but Clojure's `cons` function (implemented in `Clojure.lang.RT/cons`) is different from the `cons` methods implemented in `PersistentVector`,  `PersistentList` et cetera.

Comment: Ah, now I understand you. The way it's phrased, it sounds like you are referring to the core function `cons`.

Comment: fair enough - I edited my answer to make it clearer. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 6):

If you look at [Clojure Data Structures](http://clojure.org/data_structures)

you'll see that conj works differently with lists and vectors.

conj puts the added item at the front of the list and at the end of a vector.

I also suggest looking at [Clojure API conj](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/conj)

which has some nice examples. ClojureDocs overall has some very nice examples for most Clojure commands.