# Weird behaviour of conj

Tags: clojure

I was trying some Clojure, but now puzzled about the behavior of the "conj".
See the exaples below:

```
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 4)
[1 2 3 4]
```

Above is expected.
But now, if I do the below:

```
user=> (conj (reverse [1 2 3]) 4)
(4 3 2 1)
```

It returns (4  3  2  1). But I guess it should have returned (3 2 1 4).  So, what am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistency with Clojure's sequences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437833/inconsistency-with-clojures-sequences)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reverse` returns a list.

```
(reverse [1 2 3])
=> (3 2 1)
```

`conj` has the behavior of adding something to a collection as cheaply as possible. For vectors, it'd be appending. For lists, it'd be pre-pending.

For example:

```
(conj '(1 2 3) 4)
=> (4 1 2 3)
```

Comment: From the docs: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/conj "The 'addition' may
happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type."